# Django: BaseFormSet & url slug

Tags: django

How do I get the slug organizer from my url in my class BaseReserveFormSet? Anyone did that before? I am really struggling how to solve that.

BaseFormSet:

```
class BaseReserveFormSet(BaseFormSet):

    def clean(self):   
        queryset = Organizer.objects.filter(
            # MY PROBLEM: HOW DO I GET <slug:organizer> IN HERE?
            slug='lorem-2',
        )
        max_qty_per_ticket = queryset.first().max_qty_per_ticket
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:organizer>/<slug:event>/', event_detail_view, name='event'),
]
```

Comment: @Alasdair 
It is the same issue (which remained unanswered). I tried to break it down to 10% of my question before. If it's preferred I can also just change it in my previous question?

Comment: Yes, please update your original question instead of creating duplicates.

Comment: All right, done. I will delete that post here in the next 3 min

Comment: If you've updated your original question there is no need to update this one. No one will be able to answer it because it's closed as a duplicate.